# Parsing doubly nested JSON object to MongoDB

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

Schema for my MongoDB model:

```
var resultsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   start_date: String,
   end_date: String,
   matches:[{
       id:Number,
       match_date:String,
       status:String,
       timer:Number,
       time:String,
       hometeam_id:Number,
       hometeam_name:String,
       hometeam_score:Number,
       awayteam_id:Number,
       awayteam_name:String,
       awayteam_score:Number,
       ht_score:String,
       ft_score:String,
       et_score:String,
       match_events:[{
           id:Number,
           type:String,
           minute:Number,
           team:String,
           player_name:String,
           player_id:Number,
           result:String
       }]
    }] 
});
```

Example of JSON data coming from the server:

```
"matches":
[
    {
        "match_id":"1234"
        "match_date":"Aug 30"
        ...
        ...
        "match_events":
        [
            {
                "event_id":"234",
                "event_minute":"38",
                ...,   
                ...
            },
            { 
                "event_id":"2334",
                "event_minute":"40",
                ...,   
                ...
            }
         ],
    {
        "match_id":"454222"
        "match_date":"Aug 3"
        ...
        ...
        "match_events":
        [
            {
                "event_id":"234",
                "event_minute":"38",
                ...,   
                ...
            },
                ....
```

My current implementation works for parsing just the matches (i.e the first array). But I can't seem to access the inner array properly.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        request.get('http://football-api.com/api/?Action=fixtures&APIKey=' + apiKey + '&comp_id=' + compId +
            '&&from_date=' + lastWeek_string + '&&to_date=' + today_string, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) return next(error);
                var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

                var matches = parsedJSON.matches;
                var events = parsedJSON.matches.match_events;

                var results = new Results({
                    start_date: lastWeek_string,
                    end_date: today_string,
                    matches:[]
                });
                _.each(matches, function(match) {
                    results.matches.push({
                        id: match.match_id,
                        match_date: match.match_formatted_date,
                        status:match.match_status,
                        timer:match.match_timer,
                        hometeam_id:match.match_localteam_id,
                        hometeam_name:match.match_localteam_name,
                        hometeam_score:match.match_localteam_score,
                        awayteam_id:match.match_visitorteam_id,
                        awayteam_name:match.match_visitorteam_name,
                        awayteam_score:match.match_visitorteam_score,
                        ht_score:match.match_ht_score,
                        ft_score:match.match_ft_score,
                        et_score:match.match_et_score,
                        match_events:[]
                    });
                });
                _.each(events, function(event) {
                    results.matches.match_events.push({
                        id:event.event_id,
                        type:event.event_type,
                        minute:event.event_minute,
                        team:event.event_team,
                        player_name:event.event_player,
                        player_id:event.event_player_id,
                        result:event.event_result
                    });
                });
```

I understand that the second `_.each` loop should be iterating for every match, since very `match` has it's own `events` subarray. I'm just not sure how to structure this and have been struggling with it for a while.

I tried nesting that loop inside the `_.each(matches, function(match) {` loop but that didn't work.

Thank you.

*Edit*: How could I get this to work?

```
var results = new Results({
    start_date: lastWeek_string,
    end_date: today_string,
    matches:[
        match_events: []
    ]
});
```

Because then as @zangw says I could construct the match_events array first, append it to matches, and so on.

Comment: How about construct the `match_events` subarray first, then append it to the `matches`. At last, save the `matches` into `results`.

Comment: I would need to define the `match_events` array inside the `matches` array first to do that. See my edit.

Comment: I would like to split `match_events` as another document, and add `ref` to `matches` document. How do think about it.